# raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include(). using python-2.7 django-1.11.9

Tags: django, python-2.7

When i run 'python manage.py migrate' ,,it gives me this error ::

```
raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().') TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().
```

THE WHOLE TRACEBACK IS:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/prashant/Desktop/po/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in 
execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/prashant/Desktop/po/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/prashant/Desktop/po/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/prashant/Desktop/po/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 327, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home/prashant/Desktop/po/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/prashant/Desktop/po/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 62, in _run_checks
    issues.extend(super(Command, self)._run_checks(**kwargs))
  File "/home/prashant/Desktop/po/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/prashant/Desktop/po/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/prashant/Desktop/po/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/prashant/Desktop/po/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/prashant/Desktop/po/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/prashant/Desktop/po/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/prashant/Desktop/po/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/prashant/Desktop/po/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/prashant/Desktop/po/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/prashant/Desktop/po/cope/urls.py", line 10, in <module>
    url(r'^', include('opac.urls', namespace="opac")),
  File "/home/prashant/Desktop/po/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/prashant/Desktop/po/opac/urls.py", line 5, in <module>
    url(r'^$', 'forward'),
  File "/home/prashant/Desktop/po/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 85, in url
    raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().
```

opac/urls.py ::

```
from django.conf.urls import *

urlpatterns = ['opac.views',

    url(r'^$', 'forward'),
    url(r'^search/$', 'index'),
    url(r'^search/book/(?P<book_id>\d+)', 'get_book'),
]
```

cope/urls.py ::

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from cope import settings

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^', include('opac.urls', namespace="opac")),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from .views import forward,index,get_book

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', forward),
    url(r'^search/$', index),
    url(r'^search/book/(?P<book_id>\d+)', get_book),
]
```

use this format in your opac.urls file

Comment: Thanks for your quick response ,it does the trick !! :)
HappyCoding!